# What was the debate where Ramanandi tradition defeated Ramanuja tradition in 1921 Ujjain Kumbh mela?

Tags: history, vaishnavism, vishishtadvaita, kumbh-mela

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ujjain_Simhastha#British_era)

> The 1921 Simhastha is notable for a historic debate in which the Ramanandi Sampradaya defeated the Ramanuja sampradaya (Shri Vaishnavas). The debate was to address the question whether the Shri Vaishnava literature offended Ramachandra. The Ramanuja sampradaya was defended by Swami Ramprapann Ramanujadas of the Totadri math. The Ramanandis were represented by Bhagavadacharya (alias Bhagvad Das). The jury declared Bhagavadacharya as the winner of the debate, and Ramanandis became independent of the Ramanuja sampradaya. However, some Ramanandis continued to regard themselves as part of the Ramanuja sampradaya, alleging that Bhagavadacharya forged evidence used to win the debate and that the jury was biased. The Ramanujis were prohibited from participating in the subsequent 1932 Kumbh Mela at Ujjain.

I wanted details of the debate. Can anyone provide?

Comment: Wikipedia  provides references also. This question is not related to vishishtadvaita. The debate was about Vaishnavism and not related to philosophy.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Ramanuja tradition = Vishishtaadvait. Do want me to create new tag(s)?

Comment: Ramanuja tradition != Vishishtadvaita. It is Sri Sampradaya. Philosophy is different from bhakti tradition.

Comment: The information on Wikipedia looks like it came from [*Peasants and Monks in British India* by William R. Pinch, page 65](https://books.google.com/books?id=B7cwDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=Bhagavadacharya+%22Ramprapann+Ramanujadas%22&source=bl&ots=3GTCF-aZlt&sig=BOkmd9y4tx0x6eqB5kzUzvK_cqE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgy7acttDaAhUF7lMKHTRiD7sQ6AEINzAB#v=onepage&q&f=false). Perhaps reading the preceeding and following pages will give you more insight?